# Is the -re "supposed" to be silent in the pronunciation of "macabre"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, loanwords

Is the "-re" supposed to be silent in the pronunciation of the word *macabre*?  I'm aware that dictionaries give two pronunciations, \məkäb\ and \mekäbrə\, but is one of them just a fixed "error" of the other, when the loan word from French was first imported?  In other words, which pronunciation is more historically true?

Comment: In British, there's also /məkɑ:bɹ/ (it can be pronounced, and it sounds semi-French), and /məkɑ:bə/. The latter is why the word is sometimes also spelled *macaber*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are equally accurate Anglicized versions of the French word.  *Macabre* is basically pronounced [makabʁ] in French, where /ʁ/ is a [voiced uvular fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_fricative).  The closest sound in English is, of course, /ɹ/ (the "r" sound, hereafter written as *r*).

Note that there is a [bʁ] sequence at the end of the word.  This [ʁ] is basically stranded at the end of the word, with no real vowel connected to it.  This happens because French "e" gets deleted in many contexts (or some might say "swallowed"), including word-finally.  So "macabre" in French is pronounced basically like [makab] followed by a fricative-ʁ sound, with no "e" vowel sound after it.  To a non-native speaker, the "r" sound at the end might not even be noticeable.

We don't have anything quite like this in English, so essentially we have this "illegal" word-final [br] consonant cluster.  There are two common ways to repair an unpronounceable consonant cluster:

- One method is deletion; if we delete the [r], we pronounce the word as [məkab].
- The other method is [epenthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis), adding a vowel sound to make the cluster pronounceable. This yields [məkabrə].

This gives us the two pronunciations we see for this word.

Comment: An above and beyond answer! :)

Comment: I suspect that for a non-native speaker, the "r" is noticeable, but it is certainly not reproducible.

Comment: I would have said French "r" was a voiced uvular *trill*, but apparently that means I've spent too much time around [working class Parisians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttural_R) :-)

Comment: +1 You have to come to EL&U if you want to understand all this.  Even if you're French! Thx.

Comment: @psmears: when I learned French (poorly) many years ago, we were told to trill most "r"s, but I believe not the final ones after consonants.

Comment: The third possibility (in rhotic dialects) is to make the /R/ syllabic, which gives the pronunciation in Thursagen's answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that English got this word about 600 years ago in the time of Old French, which did not have the modern Parisian uvular pronunciation. But it's also worth noting that this word kept a bit more of its French identity than many other words. Even today French retains three 'r' pronunciations: the uvular trill like Edith Piaf, the uvular fricative like the modern Parisian standard, and a trill or tap like in Italian. Apparently that last one was the usual one 600 years ago for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

The "e" is pronounced in a schwa type of way, and the 'r' in a rhotic type of way, the way you say 'r' in "hard". The 'r' isn't pronounced the way you say "rim".

> Ma-cə-bər